Player sprite, score system, and lives system not working from Pytch
I am working on a Space Invaders game for midterm. For some odd reason my player sprite, score system, and lives system all do not work. I am not sure where to go from here and no one in my class can figure this out either.
import pytch
import random

score = 0
lives = 10

game_over = False

# Alien Sprites
class Alien(pytch.Sprite):
    Costumes = ["enemy-alien.png", "friendly-alien.png""]
    Sounds = ["explosion.mp3", "scream.mp3"]
    
    @pytch.when_I_receive("make-clones")
    def make_clones(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.go_to_xy(-150 + i * 60, 180)
            pytch.create_clone_of(self)
        self.go_to_xy(150, 180)
        

    @pytch.when_I_receive("play-game")
    def drift_down_screen(self):
            while not game_over:
                    self.set_y(180)
                    self.show()
                    glide_time = random.uniform(3.0, 5.0)
                    self.glide_to_xy(self.x_position, -180, glide_time)
                    
# The Score System
    @pytch.when_this_sprite_clicked
    def handle_hit(self):
        if self.costume_number == 0:
            self.start_sound("explosion")
        else:
            global score
            score += 10
            self.lose_life(1)
        self.hide()

    def lose_life(self):
        self.start_sound("scream")
        global lives
        lives -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            global game_over
            game_over = True
            pytch.broadcast("game-over")

    @pytch.when_I_receive("game-over")
    def do_game_over(self):
        self.hide()
        
# Background
class Galaxy(pytch.Stage):
    Backdrops = ["starry-sky.jpg"]
    Sounds = ["fizz.mp3"]

    @pytch.when_green_flag_clicked
    def run(self):
        pytch.show_variable(None, "score")
        pytch.show_variable(None, "lives", right=236)
        pytch.broadcast_and_wait("make-clones")
        pytch.broadcast("play-game")

    @pytch.when_stage_clicked
    def make_miss_sound(self):
        self.start_sound("fizz")

So far I have tried to change the ticks of the costumes and tried changing around how some of the code works. However they were just tricks where instead of using <1, I would use == 0.

the code you posted just defines some classes, but doesn't execute or run anything. Could you post a minimal reproducible example of the code that we can copy and run?

Is this the actual code you're running? Why does Costumes = ["enemy-alien.png", "friendly-alien.png""] contain an extra " at the end?

This was the code I use for the game fully through Pytch. I used most assets through the space invaders tutorial. As for the extra comma, I accidently added it as I was putting it here. The code itself should be able to run just fine inside the tutorial since it uses sources.
